# Add colorbar to existing axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, imshow

I'm making some interactive plots and I would like to add a colorbar legend. I don't want the colorbar to be in its own axes, so I want to add it to the existing axes. I'm having difficulties doing this, as most of the example code I have found creates a new axes for the colorbar.

I have tried the following code using `matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase`, which adds a colorbar to an existing axes, but it gives me strange results and I can't figure out how to specify attributes of the colorbar (for instance, where on the axes it is placed and what size it is)

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import coolwarm
import numpy as np

x = np.random.uniform(1, 10, 10)
y = np.random.uniform(1, 10, 10)
v = np.random.uniform(1, 10, 10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

s = ax.scatter(x, y, c=v, cmap=coolwarm)

matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax=ax, cmap=coolwarm, values=sorted(v),
                                 orientation="horizontal")
```

Using `fig.colorbar` instead of`matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase` still doesn't give me quite what I want, and I still don't know how to adjust the attributes of the colorbar.

```
fig.colorbar(s, ax=ax, cax=ax)
```

[image]

Let's say I want to have the colorbar in the top left corner, stretching about halfway across the top of the plot. How would I go about doing that?

Am I better off writing a custom function for this, maybe using `LineCollection`?

Comment: I have no answer to this.  However, why would you want the colorbar to be part of the existing axis as opposed to giving it a new axis?

Comment: @tnknepp I'm making interactive plots with zooming/panning, toggling plots on and off, etc. It'll just be easier for me to not have to create a new axes for the colorbar

Comment: why can't you just use `fig.colorbar(ax=ax)`?

Comment: @tom That creates a new axes for the colorbar. Doing fig.colorbar(ax=ax, cax=ax) does not create a new axes, but creates similarly strange plots. I'll add an example of what the plot looks like

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The colorbar has to have its own axes.  However, you can create an axes that overlaps with the previous one.  Then use the `cax` kwarg to tell `fig.colorbar` to use the new axes.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.arange(100, 0, -1).reshape(10, 10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cax = fig.add_axes([0.27, 0.8, 0.5, 0.05])

im = ax.imshow(data, cmap='gist_earth')
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 139):

This technique is usually used for multiple axis in a figure. In this context it is often required to have a colorbar **that corresponds in size with the result from imshow.** This can be achieved easily with the [axes grid](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/index.html) tool kit:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

data = np.arange(100, 0, -1).reshape(10, 10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)

im = ax.imshow(data, cmap='bone')

fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax, orientation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

[image: Image with proper colorbar in size]

Answer (score 11):

Couldn't add this as a comment, but in case anyone is interested in using the accepted answer with subplots, the divider should be formed on specific axes object (rather than on the numpy.ndarray returned from plt.subplots)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
data = np.arange(100, 0, -1).reshape(10, 10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2)
for row in ax:
    for col in row:
        im = col.imshow(data, cmap='bone')
        divider = make_axes_locatable(col)
        cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
        fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax, orientation='vertical')
plt.show()
```